# Error while trying to add value to database using EditText

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to insert a value from edit text to firebase. Here is the MainActivity code and XML code.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }


    public void buttonClicked(View view){

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference().child("Users");
        EditText editname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        String name_content = editname.getText().toString();
        myRef = database.getReference();
        myRef.setValue(name_content);
    }

}
```

XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.suzancruz.firebasesample.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Name"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked"
        android:text="Enter Values"
        />
```

I can't figure out what the problem actually is. As soon as I click the button after entering value in edit text the application crashes and I get the following error in log: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: Try defining your editText in the onCreate method?

Comment: @AmbujKathotiya still the same error.

Comment: can you post the updated code?

Comment: Previous code worked after cleaning the project.

Comment: So is it working now?

Comment: Yes, it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Please try keeping a reference to your `EditText` in `onCreate()`. It is expensive to find the `EditText` view every time the button is clicked.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private EditText editname;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    }


    public void buttonClicked(View view){
        //...
        String name_content = editname.getText().toString();
        //...
    }

}
```

If you insist to find the `EditText` when button is clicked, you can do it this way:

```
public void buttonClicked(View view){

    //...
    EditText editname = (EditText)view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.name);
    String name_content = editname.getText().toString();
    //...
}
```